# Does Intellij Idea persistence tool have a mapping file for converting database types to Java type?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, orm, mapping

I am trying to create hibernate Entity files for my tables in oracle database via persistence tool in Intellij IDEA. But tool maps Varchar2 types to java.lang.Object variable type instead of java.lang.String. Is there any mapping file for this. As you can see in attachment: [Database Schema Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLblu.png)

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: unfortunately, i couldnt find any solution for problem. I manually updated whole entities one by one

Comment: Yeah I feel you. I ended up installing eclipse and added Hibernate Tools in order to reverse engineer the database. I wish they would fix that as soon as possible since it's been a while.

Comment: I have the same problem with timestamps... :/

Comment: Which Idea version and DBMS are you using? It works just fine for me on 2017.1 with both Oracle and DB2.